# Draw boder outside button which is placed inside panel at run time

Tags: winforms

I am developing a window application. I have a static panel on form & Some menu like panel[image] buttons etc.
at run time I have drag a panel on static panel & add a button inside this panel. now a I want to drawn a border outside this button but when border is drawn , border take its position from static panel not from panel createdat run time.

Please provide me a sol. for this .
My code for draw border is :

```
 private void sDrawControlBorder(object sender)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        //define the border to be drawn, it will be offset by DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2
        //around the control, so when the drag handles are drawn they will be seem
        //connected in the middle.

        Rectangle Border = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(control.Size.Width + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Size.Height + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        //define the 8 drag handles, that has the size of DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE
        Rectangle NW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle N = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle NE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle W = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle E = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle S = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));

        //get the form graphic//
        g = control.Parent.CreateGraphics();
       //draw the border and drag handles//

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, Border, Color.Gray, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NW,true,true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, N, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NE, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, W, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, E, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SW, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, S, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SE, true, true);
        g.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to offset your coordinates by the coordinates of any containers (the panel in this case).

Comment: Whenever I see `CreateGraphics()`, it's a sure sign you're doing something wrong.  Always prefer the control's own `Paint` event when it's available.